# Penrose Triangle as a 4D object

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Good day guys,

I was looking at the Penrose triangle today.
I was wondering if it was possible to understand it as some sort of 2D projection of a 4D object. But I do not know how I can check this for myself to develop a better understanding of why this could be or could not be the case.

Kindest regards.

Comment: You should give at least a reference : the term "Penrose triangle" isn't known (by me, and surely by many other) as such : do you mean Penrose tiling as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) ?

Comment: The first step towards answering this would be to clarify the precise sense in which the 2D Penrose Triangle image is *not* the projection of a 3D object (capturing the idea that it depicts an impossible object). This seems tricky, since in a simpler sense every 2D figure *is* a projection of a 3D figure, and we can even make 3D models that look like the Penrose Triangle from certain directions.

Comment: You haven't answered my question... See for example [this publication](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Penrose-tiling-in-the-4D-description-can-be-visualized-in-different-hyperspace_fig3_228590314) (jump to fig. 8)

Comment: @JeanMarie I think they mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle